# How to write SOURCES file for the existing windows driver code?

Tags: windows, driver

I have downloaded a wdf serial port driver code from [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Serial-73a4564d/file/42753/40/Serial%20Port%20Driver.zip) site.Now I have to write SOURCES file for this code & I don't know how to do that.I searched on google but didn't get any reference article or site through which I can learn it.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2013? This sample contains VS2013 solution, just open it and build. You can find many code samples for WDK build by downloading Windows Driver Kit.

Comment: @AlexFarber,I know about the solution file through which we can build  it but I was asked to write SOURCES file.

Comment: Download WDK, all WDK samples don't use VS2013 solution and contain SOURCES file.

Comment: @AlexFarber, Thanks for the reply.I am able to solve above problem. Now I am facing another problem when I try to build package.
It shows that " .inf file is missing" so I have to add .inx file in sources to create driver package. Is it possible to add .inx file using sources file?

Comment: I found one [msdn link][1] which helps me to create sources file for existing driver & to include .inx file in Visual studio project I have created makefile and makefile.inc   


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms910176.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms910176.aspx) which helps me to create sources file for existing driver. And to include `.inx` file in Visual studio project I have created `makefile` and `makefile.inc`